# Subgraphs of bipartite graphs that contain complete graphs

Tags: graph-theory

> When is $K_{n}$ a subgraph of $K_{n,n}$?

It looks like from my drawing that for $n=3$ it can't be.

But I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 5):

Bipartite graphs have no odd cycles. $K_n$ contains triangles when $n\geq3$. Therefore $K_n$ is not a subgraph of $K_{n,n}$ for any $n\geq 3$.